# Delphi access violation at address when i try to initialize new form

Tags: delphi

When i try to open new child mdi form i want to check if that child form is already opened. I try to achive that with Assignet method. When i use `Assigned` i get error `Acccess violation at address`. This error tell there is no instance in memory.

```
uses SubjectUnit;

procedure TMainForm.SubjectClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Frm : TSubjectForm;
begin
  if not Assigned(TSubjectForm) then
  begin
    Frm := TSubjectForm.Create(Self);
    Frm.Show;
  end
  else
    Frm.WindowState := TWindowState.wsMaximized;
end;
```

I know what is problem but what is good way to initailze `Frm`? before `if` statement? If i initalize it i will duplicate initalization in `if` block

Comment: You need to use `Assigned` on an _instance_ of a form, not on the class type.  Also, the instance (Frm) will need to be global, not inside the event handler.  I haven't used MDI child forms for a long time, so I'm not sure if SubjectUnit already declares an instance (it will be called SubjectForm), but if so, use `Assign` on that instance, and use that instance for the `.Create` and subsequent lines.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Am realy new in Delphi i come from C# and this is litle confused. I will try

Comment: And please note that freeing that form with ``Frm.Free`` does not set its reference ``Frm`` to nil! Only ``FreeAndNil(Frm)`` or manually ``Frm := nil`` after ``.Free`` will do! So if you don't do that and use ``Assign`` again after a ``.Free`` happend, this check won't work as you think and you'll run into Access Violation errors afterwards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass a class type to `Assigned()`, you have to pass a pointer to an object instance instead.  `Assigned()` will simply tell you whether the pointer is `nil` or not, not whether it is pointing at a valid object.

So, unless you are saving your own pointers to your MDI child form objects, then `Assigned()` will not really help you anyway.

Depending on your needs, you would likely need to instead loop through the main form's `MDIChildren[]` property looking at each existing child form to see if it matches what you are looking for (ie, class type, window title, etc).

For example, if you want only 1 instance of `TSubjectForm` then you would need to do this instead:

```pascal
uses
  ..., SubjectUnit;

procedure TMainForm.SubjectClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Frm : TSubjectForm;
begin
  Frm := nil;

  for i := 0 to MDIChildCount-1 do
  begin
    if MDIChildren[i] is TSubjectForm then
    begin
      Frm := TSubjectForm(MDIChildren[i]);
      Break;
    end;
  end;

  if not Assigned(Frm) then
  begin
    Frm := TSubjectForm.Create(Self);
    Frm.WindowState := TWindowState.wsMaximized;
  end;

  Frm.Show;
end;
```

Alternatively, you can accomplish the same thing using the child Form's global pointer instead, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., SubjectUnit;

procedure TMainForm.SubjectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not Assigned(SubjectForm) then
  begin
    SubjectForm := TSubjectForm.Create(Self);
    SubjectForm.WindowState := TWindowState.wsMaximized;
  end;

  SubjectForm.Show;
end;
```

```pascal
var
  SubjectForm: TSubjectForm;

...

procedure TSubjectForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SubjectForm := nil;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in your code.

First, you cannot call `Assigned` on a class. You need to call it on a object reference `Assigned(Frm)`.

Next, local variables of unmanaged types, including object references are not automatically initialized to nil and contain random data. Calling `Assigned` on such uninitialized variable is undefined behavior and it will give random results.

```
procedure TMainForm.SubjectClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Frm : TSubjectForm;
begin
  // Frm is not initialized at this point and 
  // following check can randomly pass or fail
  if not Assigned(Frm) then
```

If you have some code logic that needs to check whether some local reference is assigned or not you need to initialize that reference to nil first.

```
procedure TMainForm.SubjectClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Frm : TSubjectForm;
begin
  Frm := nil;
  ...
  // now we can safely check whether reference points to valid object 
  // or not
  if not Assigned(Frm) then
```

However, for achieving functionality you desire above code would be useless as local variable would always be empty and such code would always create new form instance and you could end up with multiple subject forms.

From your code it seems you need to have single subject form and then you need to declare variable that will hold that form in broader context as field in the `TMainForm` class or as global variable, not in locally in the method.

```
type
  TMainForm = class(...
  ...
    fSubjectFrm: TSubjectForm;
  end;

procedure TMainForm.SubjectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not Assigned(fSubjectFrm) then
  begin
    fSubjectFrm := TSubjectForm.Create(Self);
    fSubjectFrm.Show;
  end
  else
    fSubjectFrm.WindowState := TWindowState.wsMaximized;
end;
```

Once created such subject form instance will exist as long as its owner object (in this case main form) exists.